# Is it possible to replace part of AWS API Gateway request URL?

Tags: aws-api-gateway

The following is for HTTP APIs.
At the moment I have an API Gateway custom domain defined e.g. apigateway.example.com.
I have defined a ANY /api/{proxy+} route & integration. All these work fine.
So at the moment I hit https://apigateway.example.com/api/state or [https://apigateway.example.com/api/pipelines/{pipelineID}/trigger](https://apigateway.example.com/api/pipelines/%7BpipelineID%7D/trigger) and they work fine.
Is there any way, through API mappings in custom domain section or parameter mapping in the integration to replace the /api/ in the URL with e.g. /back/?
So instead of hitting https://apigateway.example.com/api/state (which works fine now), to hit https://apigateway.example.com/back/state ? But this URL I would like to still hit the ANY /api/{proxy+} integration.

I don't understand if what I want to achieve is even possible.